# Elusive Matlab variable syntax error

Tags: matlab, variables, vector

`u` and `v` and `r` should be vectors.

```
function [g] = kast(m,k,u,v,n)
g = 9.80;
t = 0:0.1:n;
r = [u.*(m/k).*(1-exp(-k.*t./m),((-m*g/k).*t) + (v.*(m/k).+m^2*g/k^2).*( 1.-exp(-k.*t./m)))];

plot(t,r)
end
```

I've spent about an hour, but I cannot work out what is wrong. Are any of you able to spot my error?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Off topic, but if you use two digits, take `g = 9.81`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.+m^2
```

looks suspicious. Try remove the dot before the `+`. And add a closing bracket before the comma in the assignment of `r`.

Comment: @Jonas: My matlab thinks otherwise. `x.+y` throws an `Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.`

Comment: @H.Muster: Interesting. On R2013a, `1.+2` and `1.+magic(2)` both work.

Comment: @Jonas Of course it works with numbers, because `1.` is the same as `1.0`, i.e., `1.+2` gets parsed as `1.0+2`. However, if you use variables, Matlab gets upset.

Comment: @H.Muster: D'oh! I'm removing my erroneous comment. Thanks!